# Sqlite with Entity Framework in windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an application in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight with a sqlite database, but the problem is it is kind of a lengthy task to manage data using just sqlite.

Is it possible to use Entity Framework with sqlite for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

- If yes then how? Any tutorial will be helpful
- If no then: is there any better way or plugin available for managing data simply..

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to use Entity Framework on Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight or even WinRT (Windows Runtime 8.1). According to [Entity Framework Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap), EF Core available for UWP (Windows 10 apps).

I can recommend you to use SQLite.Net-PCL ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/), [GitHub](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL)). It is very lightweight ORM which supports Linq-like queries.

Comment: Thank you for quick and clean answer with proof!!!,,really appriciated..